# Secondary money market effects of expansionary monetary policy using IS-LM model

Tags: macroeconomics, money-supply, keynesian-economics

According to the basic IS-LM model, an outward shift of the LM curve results in higher output because (as shown with the money market chart) expansionary monetary policy reduces the interest rate, which stimulates investment spending.

Does this increase in output eventually produce an upward shift in the liquidity demand curve, and does this result in a higher interest rate? If so, how is this represented on the IS-LM chart? It seems to me that it wouldn't be a shift in the LM curve as this is produced solely by changes in the money supply, and it wouldn't be a shift in the IS curve as although a higher interest rate will result in less investment spending, this would be a shift along the IS curve rather than a shift of the curve itself.

Thanks.